# Can't ssh into pi anymore

Tags: raspbian, ssh

A few hours ago, I was able to SSH into my pi at the address `192.168.2.0` by doing `ssh pi@192.168.2.0`, then I got brave and tried to set up port forwarding on my router. It changed the IP ranges to things like `10.0.0.1`, but then I changed it back.

Now I can do `ping raspberrypi.local` and it is successful, sending packets. It tells me the new IP is `192.168.1.11` but now I can't ssh into it, it says: `connect to host 192.168.1.11 port 22: Connection refused`.

Any ideas?

Comment: `192.168.2.0` does not look like an IP address of your Pi.

Comment: Please describe your network configuration. Using 192.168.2.0 as device address is quite unusual, and it sounds like you have network configuration issues well beyound the Pi and SSH.

Comment: this is not a bad question, idk the downvotes. my network is configured using an apple airport extreme.

Comment: If you describe your network configuration as "using an apple airport extreme", then you should ask Apple for support, since people who don't own this gadget have no way of knowing how it works.

Comment: wait to clarify, 192.128.2.0 is the local address of the pi i'm trying to access, not the external one, sorry for the confusion. That's a standard local address right?

Comment: you can only use ".0" address if you do not have subnets.  Unless you're ssh'ing to self (so no other hosts in the subnet), most likely other hosts in the same subnet is unusable until the ".0" is removed.  (You your search engine skills and research more if needed).  Next, if "raspberrypi.local" is defined in your /etc/hosts and you're ping'ing it, it's like saying I can ping loopback/localhost...  again, it is like ssh'ing self...  Try using 'ssh -vvv' on the other endpoint to see if you can determine the cause.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local`
2. do `sudo ifconfig eth0` if using an ethernet connection to find IP.
3. do `sudo ifconfig wlan0` if using WiFi connection.
4. The "inet" address is the IP.

Comment: OPs entire issue is they *can't* ssh into the Pi...

Answer (score 0):

Recent release of Raspbian (and possibly other distributions) disables the ssh server by default. You can re-enable by either creating a file called **ssh** in /boot or by enabling it in raspi-config.

Comment: The OP didn't say anything about reflashing, he only changed router settings.

Comment: it's enabled and i just checked it to make sure, plus i SSHed in a couple days ago, i just can't anymore